# Writing "Hello World!" in NASM

Tags: x86-64, nasm, win64

Whenever I try to run it, "hello.exe" waits a second then ends without writing anything.

Source code:

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        mov rax,1
        mov rdi,1
        mov rsi,msg
        mov rdx,13
        syscall
        mov rax,60
        xor rdi,rdi
        syscall
section .data
    msg:db "Hello World!",10
```

Compile command:

> ```
> ../../../bin/NASM/nasm.exe -f win64 hello.asm
> ```

> ```
> ../../../bin/Golink/Golink.exe /console hello.obj
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The source code is intended for Linux machines, but you are on a Windows (`win64`).